# col-sm-12 not having a width of 100% on smartphones - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

Breakpoints definition SASS:

```
/* For the grid */
$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 576px,
    md: 768px,
    lg: 992px,
    xl: 1200px,
    xxl: 1440px,
    xxxl: 1660px
);
```

My columns are like this:

```html
<div id="footer_lower_menus" class="row">
    <div class="fui_col col col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="fui_col col col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="fui_col col col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**Expected result:** The columns should be one third on size lg (and bigger like xl), one half on size md and full width on size sm (or smaller like xs).

**Actual result:** For the big sizes it works, but for sizes smaller than sm (xs, which seems not to be compiled as it is zero) the columns are becoming one half or one third again (not taking any of the definitions?).

Note: The contents contain text and seem to have a "max-width" of 100%.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I apply "sm or smaller" instead of "sm only"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `col` from class list and run your code and check again it will gives you full-width content.

The reason to remove the `col` class is that it divides your row into equal parts.  That means if you use `<div class="col">text</div>` 5 times in a single row then it will divide your row space equally - which means each `col` will be of 20% width.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>Teste</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="footer_lower_menus" class="row">
      <div class="fui_col col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        fui_col 1
      </div>
      <div class="fui_col col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        fui_col 2
      </div>
      <div class="fui_col col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        fui_col 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Blackbam please check my updated answer for more clarification.

Comment: @KildipKoradia You were right, its the col  Thanks for the good explanation.